# Best way tie a list to a second SQL table in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need some tips on how to best handle an implementation before diving down a rabbit hole. I'm trying to build a poll talking MVC app in ASP.NET. I have a class for the poll, which has properties for Id, and Name.  I then have a PollOption class which has properties such as Id, Name, VoteCount and some other properties.

I'd like to be able to store a list of PollOptions in the Poll object when it gets created. I just won't know how many PollOptions will be needed and keep reading that SQL cannot store a list in the table anyway.

Just looking for how you would handle this so any tips/pointers would be much appreciated! I'm a beginner in C# and not sure what to search for to build this tool.

Comment: SQL can store a list, sure - that's what rows are for! You need a poll table, and a poll options table. In the options table you store the ID of the poll which the option belongs to. This is called a one-to-many relationship. In the database you usually implement this concept by means of a primary and foreign key. I suggest you study the basics of relational database design before you go any further with this, and then such a table structure would be obvious to you.

Comment: And then once you have that, you can easily use your C# to write a SELECT query or two to pull the relevant data. If you use an ORM like Entity Framework it makes these kinds of queries even simpler to code. Again I suggest you study some books/tutorials on the basics and follow some examples to build a basic application and get the ideas. Then you can apply them to your poll idea. It sounds like you have almost no knowledge of the fundamental aspects of this, and that's too much for us to teach you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list must be a foreign key. Add a foreign key attribute to the object. If you are using entity Framework, this must be very easy. 
But your question is difficult to understand what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: This was perfect. Just needed to read up on foreign key. Thanks for helping a beginner!